# Installing Windows XP (SP3) from USB stick on a Netbook with only FreeDOS

Tags: windows-xp, boot, usb

Recently I bought an Asus X201E-KX179D netbook and it has no Windows installed on it, only the BIOS. No DVD Drive, no OS installed.

When I start my netbook, I get three options:

1. Load FreeDOS with maximum RAM free using EMM386
2. Load FreeDOS including HIMEM XMS-memory driver
3. Load FreeDOS without drivers

And I get the option to press:

F5=Bypass startup files
F8=Confirm each line of CONFIG.SYS/AUTOEXEC.BAT

I copied the Windows XP (SP3) .iso image file to my pendrive (Scandisk-8GB) using Rufus and made my USB ready for boot as well.

However, when I insert my USB and enter BIOS setup for changing boot priority, USB Boot is not shown in the boot options, or it is not recognising the USB. When I restart my netbook with the USB inserted, again it goes back to Freedos mode.

Kindly help me to install windows xp (SP3) or Windows 7 (Which is the best option?).

Additional info: USB Ports (Unlocked) in BIOS Setup

Answer (score 1):

Use flast boot software to make your USB bootable correctly.
Here is link for flash Boot- http://www.prime-expert.com/flashboot/

Answer (score 0):

When I bought my Asus netbook I had the same problem as you.
I believe that you have a 64 bit architecture so when you create the USB installation disk you need to make sure you are working on a win 64 bit version.

(I would advise you to install windows 7 on this machine)

Go to command line in an elevated mode to prepare your USB pendrive and type in the following:

**- SELECT DISK X (with the list disk command you can determine which disk is our USB device)
- CLEAN
- CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY
- SELECT PARTITION 1
- ACTIVE
- FORMAT FS=NTFS
- ASSIGN X (Here you can give a letter of your choice to the USB device)
- EXIT**

After exiting DISKPART you need to insert the Windows installation disk (64bit) into the drive and in CMD type in the following:

- D: (assuming drive D is dvd rom I put D)
- CD BOOT
- BOOTSECT.EXE /NT60 E: (assuming drive E is your USB device)

With this command you just made the USB device Bootable so that next time windows starts up it will be able to boot from the disk itself.

There is one more thing left to do is to copy the windows DVD content onto the USB device.
Just copy and paste everything from the Windows 7 64 bit installation disk to the USB.